# How to achieve zero downtime while migrating an app that uses ES from Springboot 1.5.x to 2.x

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, high-availability, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is there any elegant way to migrate spring boot apps that use Elasticsearch with no downtime?

Springboot 1.5 is about to end-of-life soon, so it's time to upgrade to 2.x. 
It's known, that SDES 2.x included in boot's release train can't work with ES 5 and above. So, I still have Elasticsearch 2.4.6 on production.

SDES of version 3, that works with springboot 2, can't work with Elasticsearch 2.x. I tried to connect using transport client of version 5 and was wondered by very funny message in ES logs:

```
Received message from unsupported version: [5.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [2.0.0]
```

In other words, it's not possible neither use old code with new Elasticsearch nor use old Elasticsearch with new code.

Have no idea what should be upgraded first. Hope someone had similar problem and can advise some kind of workaround to make things happen.

Answer (score 2):

> Springboot 1.5 is about to end-of-life soon

[Spring Boot 1.x was EOL'd on August 1st, 2019](https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/30/spring-boot-1-x-eol-aug-1st-2019)

> Is there any elegant way to migrate spring boot apps that use Elasticsearch with no downtime?

There are a variety of methods you can do, but it all boils down to your setup. There are two commonly used methods:

1. [Blue-green deployment](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html)
2. [Canary release](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CanaryRelease.html)

But again, it all depends on your setup.